# Jsoup HTML extraction without script code

Tags: java, html, jsoup, web-inspector

I trying to extract an HTML from URL with Jsoup, but during the extraction appear a script code into a div tag. Checking the HTML with the "inspect", I see only HTML tag. How can I extract only the HTML tags as result of script?

With the inspect I see:

```
<div class="container__fsbody" id="fsbody">
<div id="live-table"><div class="tabs"><div class="tabs__group"><div class="tabs__tab selected">
....
```

With the Jsoup extraction I see:

```
       <div class="container__fsbody" id="fsbody"> 
    <div id="live-table"> 
     <script>
    document.body.classList.toggle("loading", true);
</script> <span class="loadingOverlay"> 
      <div class="loadingAnimation">
```

Comment: JSoup will only see HTML, and can see nothing generated by JavaScript, I'm afraid

Comment: Could you tell me if exist a way ti obtain these informazioni generated by JavaScript?

Comment: There is no way using JSoup, but please check the duplicate which has answers that go into just this issue and possible ways to solve it.